# Unix timestamp to date coffescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, date, coffeescript, timestamp

First and foremost I know I should be using javascript and not coffeescript but I am just tweaking someone else's code to see if this works. However, I don't think it matters much for this... So the question is, how do I get the details of the date and possibly transform it into a string after getting it from the timestamp. As of now what I am doing is:

```
 date = Date(msg.timestamp)
 $("#messages").append($('<li>').html(date + ' : '+ name + ': '   + msg.message));
```

(the .html is because name is in bold)

So far I'm getting something like Mon Sep 07 2015 03:49:49 GMT+0100 (Hora de Verão de GMT), and I really just want the hours. I've tried `Date(msg.timestamp).getHours()` but haven't had any results. Maybe I should turn that it into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date(msg.timestamp).getHours()` will get the hours from the timestamp.

This works because it created a new Date object. Calling `Date()` without `new` just returns a string with the current time (not even based on the parameter you passed to it).

Comment: @PedroAbreu: there is probably something wrong with your timestamp. What are the values of `msg.timestamp` and `typeof msg.timestamp`?

Comment: ok I got it. 1441598769679 but it comes back as a string. Dumb me.